# Word meaning coincidence of reference to the unusual

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests

Most of us have had the experience of stumbling over a new fact or bit of knowledge and then finding several more references to it in the near future.  For example, you see a strange word which you're forced to look-up and then the next day the same word appears in the headline of your local paper.  There's a term for this phenomenon but I've been unable to track it down.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Great question. I've run into this phenomenon from time to time, and would love to know a word for it. Welcome to the site!

Comment: I'll add to this a statistician’s point of view: [beware of the rare event](http://wordplay.blogs.nytimes.com/2010/07/19/numberplay-rare-coincidences-are-very-common/)

Comment: Er, you posted "atavism" and "avatistic". Perhaps you meant "atavistic"?

Comment: For one thing, you can rest assured that this does not only happen to you. It is quite common to learn something, or see/hear of something, for the first time in your entire life, and then within a week, you’ll have seen it half a dozen times in the most unexpected places. I too have occasionally wondered whether this sort-of-kind-of-a-little-bit _déjà vu_-like phenomenon has a word, but I am not aware of one.

Comment: I like "coincidence."

Comment: ...But am reminded of "bagatelle" from the novel Sophie's World by Jostein Gaarder. Also "felicity," "serendipity," and (from the other side) "survival bias," "subjective validation."

Answer (score 16):

I think you might be thinking of [*synchronicity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity).

Comment: He might also be looking for the *Baader-Meinhof phenomenon*, not being able to track it down because Wikipedia [no longer has an article](http://deletionpedia.dbatley.com/w/index.php?title=Baader-Meinhof_phenomenon_%28deleted_24_Jul_2008_at_20:31%29) on that term.

Comment: I think that, despite what that deleted article says, the Baader-Meinhof phenomenon is just a type of synchronicity. But interesting find, thanks!

Comment: @RegDwight: Sometimes the Wiki moves in mysterious ways... I noticed this deletion before and never understood the rationale behind it: at least it deserves a paragraph in *Recency Effect* or *Synchronicity*; the current disambiguation page doesn't explain it at all.

Comment: RegDwight, I can offer you the bounty, but you've not commented.

Answer (score 9):

As others note, some call it the [Baader-Meinhof phenomenon](http://www.damninteresting.com/the-baader-meinhof-phenomenon) and it is somewhat close to [*synchronicity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronicity).  It is also related to the [*recency effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_position_effect#Recency_effect).  The psychological term for it seems to be the [*primacy effect*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_position_effect#Primacy_effect) or [*priming*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_%28psychology%29)

Answer (score 7):

It's called the *Baader-Meinhof Phenomenon*. Read more on [Damn Interesting](http://www.damninteresting.com/the-baader-meinhof-phenomenon).

Comment: now can I give myself this bounty :P

Answer (score 2):

That would be a form of [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias). "Synchronicity" is a pop-psychology term.

Comment: No. Seeing something because you've recently seen it, is not the same as seeing things because it's what you expect.

Comment: Frequency illusion is the psychological term you are looking for.

Comment: It is not intrinsically a bias to encounter things in a cluster. There could be a cause leading to the increase. If you simply are paying attention to something that was already happening, but you are noticing it because you finally identified it, sure, that could be a biased perception, but that's hardly certain.

Answer (score 2):

The "official" term is "frequency illusion."

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you told us more about the context(s) where "frequency illusion" and if you told us what agency considerers it "official."

Answer (score 0):

I have heard it referred to as 'Cognitive Resonance'. If you have recently heard about a new phenomenon you are more likely to notice it again. (and again, and again...)

But 'Frequency Illusion' is apparently the preferred name.