# A single word for a psychological bias

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word meaning coincidence of reference to the unusual](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5418/word-meaning-coincidence-of-reference-to-the-unusual)

What is that psychological bias called when you come across a particular term and then end up finding it everywhere for the next few days?

Comment: can I know why the post is closed, if there is no satisfying answer on the duplicate post?

Comment: Sure. The post is closed to prevent duplication of effort. If the answer to the original question doesn't satisfy you, you can always offer a bounty on it (which you just did) or provide a better answer yourself (which you just did, too). No point in splitting that information into several questions. On a separate note, what makes *me* scratch my head is that you're expressly asking for a *single* word here, and yet Martha's answer "synchronicity" doesn't satisfy you, but your very own "Baader-Meinhof phenomenon" does.

Comment: Okay I'll tell you why. See, I thought there would be a word in the English(or French maybe) to describe this. As it turns out there is a phenomenon possibly named after the scientists who discovered it or did research on it. I'm still looking for a term in the English language that could describe it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I don't know if anyone has suggested "confirmation bias", which is the answer.

Comment: [Andreas Baader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Baader) and [Ulrike Meinhof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulrike_Meinhof) were co-founders of the [Red Army Faction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Army_Faction), aka the Baader-Meinhof Group. They were terrorists, not scientists. The phenomenon is named after them, but they didn't discover it and they didn't do any research on it. They robbed banks, bombed buildings, and killed people.